# Keycloak springboot adapter does not allowed to set keycloak.policy-enforcer-config.user-managed-access property

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, authorization, keycloak

I try to secure my application with the springboot adapter. After digging inside the source code, i have see something that seems to be a bug inside the implementation.

Inside the KeycloakAdapterPolicyEnforcer class, the method getPermissionTicket that retrieve permissions for a user contains this :

```
private String getPermissionTicket(PathConfig pathConfig, PolicyEnforcerConfig.MethodConfig methodConfig, AuthzClient authzClient, OIDCHttpFacade httpFacade) {
    if (getEnforcerConfig().getUserManagedAccess() != null) {
        ProtectionResource protection = authzClient.protection();
        PermissionResource permission = protection.permission();
        PermissionRequest permissionRequest = new PermissionRequest();

        permissionRequest.setResourceId(pathConfig.getId());
        permissionRequest.setScopes(new HashSet<>(methodConfig.getScopes()));

        Map<String, List<String>> claims = resolveClaims(pathConfig, httpFacade);

        if (!claims.isEmpty()) {
            permissionRequest.setClaims(claims);
        }

        return permission.create(permissionRequest).getTicket();
    }

    return null;
}
```

`getEnforcerConfig().getUserManagedAccess() != null` is always null if you have not defined the keycloak.policy-enforcer-config.user-managed-access property inside the application.properties.

But i can't define it because of the `PolicyEnforcerConfig` class that defines the field userManagedAccess as a UserManagedAccessConfig object

```
@JsonProperty("user-managed-access")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
private UserManagedAccessConfig userManagedAccess;
```

but not provides any jackson convertor to passe from String to UserManagedAccessConfig

Without this config property set, the adapter just reject every requests. Any workaround for this issue?

Comment: did you ever get this figured out? I have the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, I just use a bean instead of property file. Something like this :

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = SecurityAutoConfiguration.class)
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public KeycloakSpringBootProperties properties() {
        final KeycloakSpringBootProperties props = new KeycloakSpringBootProperties();
        final PolicyEnforcerConfig policyEnforcerConfig = new PolicyEnforcerConfig();
        policyEnforcerConfig.setEnforcementMode(EnforcementMode.ENFORCING);
        policyEnforcerConfig.setUserManagedAccess(new UserManagedAccessConfig());
        props.setPolicyEnforcerConfig(policyEnforcerConfig);
        return props;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@scandinave's answer does not support `keycloak.policy-enforcer-config.*` properties defined in application properties. There is 'dirty' workaround  as below for this as suggested in the [discussion](https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-dev/2019-January/011555.html), which can keep the policy enforcer config properties and just add the UserManagedAccessConfig object.

```
public class KeycloakUMAConfigResolver extends KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver {

    public KeycloakUMAConfigResolver() throws Exception {
    }

    public void configureUMAConfig() {
        try {
            Field f = KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver.class.getDeclaredField("adapterConfig");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            KeycloakSpringBootProperties properties = (KeycloakSpringBootProperties) f.get(this);

            properties.getPolicyEnforcerConfig()
                    .setUserManagedAccess(new PolicyEnforcerConfig.UserManagedAccessConfig());
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Then create this config resolver bean in the security configuration.

```
    @Bean
    public KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver() throws Exception {
        return new KeycloakUMAConfigResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("dummy bean")
    public Object dummyBeam(KeycloakUMAConfigResolver configResolver) {
        configResolver.configureUMAConfig();
        return new Object();
    }
```

Note: trying to set the UserManagedAccessConfig in constructor fails due to unavailablity of adapterConfig field during the object initialization within the constructor. Hence used a dummy bean definition and then called the `configureUMAConfig` method.

Comment: can I please ask what is the use if `user-managed-access`? I'm really interested to know